# How to weakly subscribe to events/observables

Tags: events, f#, observable, weak-references

I have a static-like (publisher lifetime = application lifetime) event I need to subscribe to from views. I have no way of reliably determining when the view is navigated away from (navbar back button pressed in a Xamarin.Forms NavigationPage being one example), so I can't determine when the view should unsubscribe from the observable. (I know it's possible to subscribe/unsubscribe in OnAppearing/OnDisappearing, but that carries its own set of problems I won't go into detail about here.)

Thus, I find myself in need of having the view subscribe weakly to the event, i.e. allow the view to be garbage collected without having to unsubscribe from the event. Ideally I'd like something that can be used along the lines of `myObj.myEvent |> Observable.AsWeak |> Observable.Subscribe ...`, or `myObj.myEvent |> Observable.SubscribeWeakly ...`, or simply `myObj.myEvent.SubscribeWeakly ...`.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement this. I have heard of the [System.WeakReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but this is all very new to me and I have no idea how to properly use it - most examples I've seen seem overly complicated for what I'm trying to do, which means that either I want something different, or there's many more pitfalls beneath the surface than I suspect.

How can I subscribe to events/observables in F# while allowing the subscriber to be garbage collected without unsubscribing?

Similar but not duplicate questions:

- [Do F# observable events obviate, mediate, or are not related to the need for weak references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417616/do-f-observable-events-obviate-mediate-or-are-not-related-to-the-need-for-wea) The question asks whether weak references are needed at all in F#, not how to implement the functionality as described above. The only answer to the question is also not helpful in this regard.

Comment: Can't you just 'override OnParentSet()' and 'if(Parent == null)' unsubscribe there. It should always get called as long as the view is removed from the screen/it's parent like when popping a page by hitting the back button.

Comment: That's [not guaranteed to work](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37204/view-lifecycle-know-when-a-view-is-removed), but thanks for the tip. (The main problem with OnAppearing, btw, is that on iOS it's called *after* the view has fully appeared.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do F# observable events obviate, mediate, or are not related to the need for weak references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417616/do-f-observable-events-obviate-mediate-or-are-not-related-to-the-need-for-wea)

Comment: @Funk I read that question and its answer a few times before posting, but it did not help and it's not a duplicate. I've updated the question to explain this.

Comment: It would probably help if you approach this as a general .NET question and translate whatever you find into F#. I do not have a ready-made answer here, but one well-described pattern (used in WPF) is decoupling publishers and subscribers using an intermediary `WeakEventManager` (see [this post and the links there](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/08/06/preventing-event-based-memory-leaks-weakeventmanager/)). I won't be surprised if Xamarin already has a corresponding solution.

Comment: I get ya, the problem is that I'm still very fresh at F# and am having trouble translating the stuff I've already found into F#. I think, however, I might have found a solution now. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have arrived at a relatively simple function that seems to work correctly, though I don't really know what I'm doing, so I've put this up at [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174127/63047). It's based on information from Samuel Jack's [Weak Events in .Net, the easy way](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2012/03/weak-events-in-net-easy-way.html) as well as solution 4 in CodeProject's [Weak Events in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29922/Weak-Events-in-C#heading0005).

### Implementation

```
module Observable =
    open System

    // ('a -> 'b -> unit) -> 'a -> IObservable<'b>
    let subscribeWeakly callback target source = 

        let mutable sub:IDisposable = null
        let mutable disposed = false
        let wr = new WeakReference<_>(target)

        let dispose() =
            lock (sub) (fun () -> 
                if not disposed then sub.Dispose(); disposed <- true)

        let callback' x =
            let isAlive, target = wr.TryGetTarget()
            if isAlive then callback target x else dispose()

        sub <- Observable.subscribe callback' source
        sub
```

### Usage example

See the `WeakSubscriber` type below.

### Important

You have to use the callback's `me` parameter to invoke the relevant method. If you use `this` inside the callback, you'll still end up with a strong reference for reasons described in the aforementioned articles. For the same reason (I guess?), you can't invoke a "plain" function in the class defined using `let`. (You can, however, define the method as `private`.)

### Testing

Helper classes:

```
type Publisher() =
    let myEvent = new Event<_>()
    [<CLIEvent>] member this.MyEvent = myEvent.Publish
    member this.Trigger(x) = myEvent.Trigger(x)


type StrongSubscriber() =

    member this.MyMethod x = 
        printfn "Strong: method received %A" x

    member this.Subscribe(publisher:Publisher) =
        publisher.MyEvent |> Observable.subscribe this.MyMethod
        publisher.MyEvent |> Observable.subscribe 
                             (fun x -> printfn "Strong: lambda received %A" x)


type WeakSubscriber() =

    member this.MyMethod x = 
        printfn "Weak: method received %A" x

    member this.Subscribe(publisher:Publisher) =
        publisher.MyEvent |> Observable.subscribeWeakly
                             (fun (me:WeakSubscriber) x -> me.MyMethod x) this
        publisher.MyEvent |> Observable.subscribeWeakly
                             (fun _ x -> printfn "Weak: lambda received %A" x) this
```

The actual test:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let pub = Publisher()

    let doGc() =
        System.GC.Collect()
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        System.GC.Collect()
        printfn "\nGC completed\n"

    let someScope() =
        let strong = StrongSubscriber()
        let weak = WeakSubscriber()
        strong.Subscribe(pub)
        weak.Subscribe(pub)

        doGc() // should not remove weak subscription since it's still in scope
        printfn "All subscribers should still be triggered:"
        pub.Trigger(1)

    someScope()

    doGc() // should remove weak subscriptions
    printfn "Weak subscribers should not be triggered:"
    pub.Trigger(2)

    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

    0
```

Output:

```
GC completed

All subscribers should still be triggered:
Strong: method received 1
Strong: lambda received 1
Weak: method received 1
Weak: lambda received 1

GC completed

Weak subscribers should not be triggered:
Strong: method received 2
Strong: lambda received 2
```